# TypeError: $(...).parents(...).size is not a function

Tags: jquery, typeerror

I have a basic script which allows me to click on the website's background, excluding `#content`.

After upgrading jQuery to 3.1.0 version, I get this error:
`TypeError: $(...).parents(...).size is not a function`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#background").click(function(e) {
      if (e.target.id == "wrapper" || $(e.target).parents("#wrapper").size()) 
      {
        // do nothing
      } 
      else
      {
        window.open('http://example.com');
      }
    });
  })
</script>`
```

I don't know how to fix it. jQuery is loaded properly. Please help.

Comment: You can also try http://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin to shim the deprecated functions.

Comment: same issue for $(...).find(..).size

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`size()` was deprecated years ago and removed in version 3 ... use `length` instead

```
if (e.target.id == "wrapper" || $(e.target).parents("#wrapper").length)
```

All you had to do was look this up in the [`size() docs`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) to find this out

Comment: I focused more on "parents". Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Please use ['length'](https://api.jquery.com/length/) like [@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) suggested. But I was unable to trace from where the error was getting displayed, hence I ended up with below.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        size: function () {
            return $(this).length;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```