# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).not(...).size is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, uploadify, uploadifive

I am using [uploadify](https://github.com/RonnieSan/uploadify) to upload file in laravel with progressbar implementation. but when I am uploading file, I am getting this error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).not(...).size is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery.uploadifive.js:814)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at S.fn.init.upload (jquery.uploadifive.js:770)
    at S.fn.init.$.fn.uploadifive (jquery.uploadifive.js:872)
    at <anonymous>:1:19
```

I am using laravel and the blade view is
**uploadForm.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.artist')
@section('content')
<div id="queue"></div>
    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" multiple="true">
    <a style="position: relative; top: 8px;" href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload')">Upload Files</a>
@endsection

@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
                'auto'             : false,
                'checkScript'      : '',
                'fileType'         : 'image/png',
                'formData'         : {
                                       '_token'     : "{{csrf_token()}}"
                                     },
                'queueID'          : 'queue',
                'uploadScript'     : "{{route('track.upload')}}",
                'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) { console.log(data); }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

and my controller is this
**TrackController.php**

```
function upload(Request $request) {
    $title = rand(1000000, 9999999);
    $request->file_upload->storeAs('public/uploads', $title.'.png');
    $response = ['status' => 'ok', 'message' => $title.' successfully uploaded.'];
    return response()->json($response);
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: $(...).parents(...).size is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002951/typeerror-parents-size-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 4):

The [`size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/) method was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed entirely in 3.0 and higher. You should use `length` instead.

That call appears to be coming from the `uploadifive()` library you're using. As such I would assume that library is very outdated. I'd suggest finding an alternative.

Comment: Thanks! Rory. I will go for some other library.

Comment: No problem, glad to help/